# How do I make my navigation bar non-responsive on Twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently designing a webpage using Twitter Bootstrap, and on my page I want a navigation bar attached to the top of the page that will collapse when the width of the page is reduced, and a second navigation bar fixed to the bottom of the page that won't collapse when the page is reduced, as it will just have some social media icons on it.

The issue being that I want the top navigation bar to be responsive while the bottom one not being responsive.

Is this possible on using Bootstrap 3, what I have so far for the bottom nav bar is as follows:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "container">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't use responsive anywhere on your site, you can download a custom build of Bootstrap, without the responsiveness from http://getbootstrap.com/customize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `navbar-nav` from your unordered list and add `display:inline-block` to your list-items like this:

HTML:

```
<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class = "container">
        <ul class = "nav navBot">
            <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navBot li  {
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/41/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make the navbar non-responsive will be giving `.navbar` fixed width like `600px` .